# List comprehension bugging on one string which seems not to be '' or "\r\n"

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I read a file, containing a list of numbers, (which are some identifiers that I need later).

If there is an empty line at the end of my file, I have a bug in the following code:

```
return [ int(x)  for x in lines if not x == '' and not x == "\r\n"]
```

with the following python output:

```
  [...]
File "Z:\Projects\PyIntegrate\perforceIntegration.py", line 453, in readChange
ListNumbers
    self.changeListNumbers = loadChangeListNumbers()
  File "Z:\Projects\PyIntegrate\perforceIntegration.py", line 88, in loadChangeL
istNumbers
    return [ int(x)  for x in lines if not x == '' and not x == "\r\n"]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

obviously my test `if not x == '' and not x == "\r\n"` is not sufficient for handling this situation.

What do I do wrong ?

(everything is ok if I suppress the last empty line of my file, i.e. if i let the last line of my file containing really a number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
return [ int(line) for line in lines if line.strip() ]
```

This will `strip` all spaces and newlines from the `line` and if it is not empty (i.e. it contains some characters, preferably numbers), it will convert it into `int`.

It will however fail (and raise `ValueError`) if your file contains other characters than digits or it contains spaces between digits.

Comment: it's ok, if it raises exception in that case, because it would be against what's exepcted. your answer is perfect for my use case. and it works ;-)